# Prove that a set is bounded 3

Tags: general-topology

I have a question.

I have to show that the following set is bounded: 
 $$V = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x_i|≤ \alpha_i,i = 1,...,n\} $$

You can see that $|x_i|$ is always bounded, but how to prove this formally?

Thank you

Comment: The given definition of $V$ seems enough to say that it is bounded. So how else do you define boundedness ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see that the set is contained in $$\overline{B^n(0, \alpha)}$$ where $\alpha=\sqrt{n}\max\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots, \alpha_n\}$

---

Here, $B^n(x_0, r)$ denotes a ball centered around $x$ with a radius of $r$, i.e.

$$B^n(x_0,r)=\{x\in\mathbb R^n: \|x-x_0\|<r\}.$$

You can show that, for every $x\in V$, you have $$\|x-0\|=\|x\|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+\dots + |x_n|^2}\leq \sqrt n\alpha$$